# editing a newly added row using jeditable and on() in jQuery 1.7 from a button

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I have a data table and I add rows from a button at the top of the table. I also am able to select rows. I would also like to be able to edit those selected rows even if they are newly added. I use something like this to select a row even if it's newly added.

```
$("table").on("click", 'tr', {someinfo}, this.onRowSelected);
```

I would like to do something similar to edit the selected row. So I have an edit button, and when I press it, I want the selected row to be ready to edit (using jeditable). 
I have seen [Jeditable - Activate edit of X by clicking on Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366595/jeditable-activate-edit-of-x-by-clicking-on-y?lq=1), but I can't seem to figure out how to handle the `.editable()`. Since the `.editable()` needs to be live, I want to use `.on()` to add it in. Does anyone have an idea what the syntax for that would look like?

Here is the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darthghandi/xVuTV/27/)

Everything but the jeditable stuff works fine. Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle on jsfiddle? It's a little too difficult to spot the problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out. With some help from a more experienced javascript guy, I figured out these things:

1. The `.editable()` needs to be done before the event is triggered.
2. The `.trigger()` needs to be called from the element that has the `editable()`.

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darthghandi/xVuTV/40/) that works except for updating after editing (I was just having some fun with the JSON stuff. It's a fiddle isn't it?)