# X- editable how can I activate a particular div with click of an externam element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my question

I am working on x-editable I implemented it and it is working.

But now I need to activate the editable with the click of an external element

I got a solution like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.clickme").click(function(){
        $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
    });
});
```

[Jeditable - Activate edit of X by clicking on Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366595/jeditable-activate-edit-of-x-by-clicking-on-y)
(reference for above code)

but it is only activating the portion the input box is not showing.

any help will be really appreciated.