# Jeditable element not responding to generated click

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am trying to use an icon next to a jQuery Jeditable field. The idea is that the user can click on either the email address itself, or the icon, and the text will become editable. **Currently, the email address becomes editable if you click on the text, but not if you click on the icon.**

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="preview_source" value="email" checked>
    &nbsp;
    <span id="id_preview_email_address_container" class="clickable" style="display: inline;">
        the person
        <span id="id_preview_email_address" class="editable">{{ preview_email }}</span>
        <i class="icon-pencil jeditable-activate clickable"></i>
    </span>
</label>
```

I am using the following function to listen for the click on the pencil icon, which generates a click event on the email address text:

```js
$('.jeditable-activate').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.editable').click(); 
   // I know this is a bit clunky, but this is part of a large and 
   // complicated template system, so I can't easily simplify this 
   // selection without having to edit 20+ other files
});
```

I added some console.log()s to check that the listener was working; I can confirm that clicking on the icon definitely does generate the click() event on the email address text - it's just not giving me the input field. I've attempted to modify a few of the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366595/jeditable-activate-edit-of-x-by-clicking-on-y/366704) but with no luck. I've also tried the usual 'wrap it in a `$(document).ready()`' but for once it's not solved it!

Comment: Try trigging the event like $(document).on('click','.jeditable-activate',function(){**HERE**})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about the `<label>` tag means the jeditable plugin doesn't work as expected. The click on the icon is registering, the text is being made into an input field, but the `<label>` element just flipped it right back to text again. No idea why clicking on the text itself worked though.

To fix this, I changed the HTML like so:

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="preview_source" value="email" checked>
    &nbsp;
    <span id="id_preview_email_address_container" class="clickable">the person with address </span>
</label>
<span id="id_preview_email_address" class="editable">abc@123.com</span>
<i class="icon-pencil jeditable-activate clickable"></i>
```